# memory leak while binding data with rxSwift

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments, rx-swift

When I try to bind my `UITextField` which is in my `ViewController` with variable `var location = Variable<String?>("")` which is in my `ViewControllerViewModel` using `rxSwift` I recieve an information about memory leak. I do it like bellow:

> My ViewController

```
class ViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var locationTextField: UITextField!
    var viewControllerViewModel: ViewControllerViewModel?
    lazy var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    /*
        Another variables etc.
    */

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        bindDataWithViewModel()
    }

    func bindDataWithViewModel() {
        if let viewModel = viewControllerViewModel {
            locationTextField.rx.text.bindTo(viewModel.location).disposed(by: disposeBag) -> // here shows memory leak
        }
    }
}
```

> My ViewControllerViewModel

```
class ViewControllerViewModel {

    var location = Variable<String?>("")
    var infoStruct = InfoStruct()
    lazy var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init() {
        initValueObservable()
    }

    func initValueObservable() {
        location.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] text in
        self.infoStruct.location = text
    }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea why this memory leak creates itself and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I had the same issue is when I use textField.rx.text the resource count always increase. For more detail, My test case is I have 2 screens is A and B. At A, resource count is 56. When I push to B (B has a TextField and I used textField.rx.text ) and back to A, the resource count is 60. It ups  4 each time I push and back. Someone can explain for that, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
func bindDataWithViewModel() {

    if let viewModel = viewControllerViewModel {
        locationTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
            .bindTo(viewModel.location)
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag) // use addDisposableTo
    }
}
```

Comment: `addDisposableTo` is a deprecated method